# setting position of x-axis for gui label.......In Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-engine

i am making a game in which i am using gui label i want to set position of x axis like that when first character appears 2nd must appear a little further i am using.

```
var isClicked : boolean=false;
var xpos: float = 200;
var xpox:float; 
var i:float;

function Start () {}
function xchange(): float{

xpos= xpos+8;
i=xpos;
return i;

}
function OnMouseDown()
{
   isClicked = true;
}

function OnGUI()
{
   if (gameObject.name == "Sphere 1(Clone)" && isClicked ){
   xpox=xchange();
   GUI.Label(new Rect(xpox,260,400,100), "B");
}     

   else if (gameObject.name == "Sphere(Clone)" && isClicked ){
   xpox=xchange();
     GUI.Label(new Rect(xpox,260,400,100), "A");
   }
 }
```

in this code every time i click sphere the alphabet appears but the problem is every time the alphabet appear it start on the screen it is due to this portion of code.

```
function xchange(): float
{ 
  xpos= xpos+8;
  i=xpos;
  return i;
}
```

I just want that every alphabet that i click must appear a little further from first one.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

in function Update() just check condition isClicked = true or not..

```
function Update()
{
      if(isClicked)
      {
           xpos += 500; 
      }
}

function OnGUI()
{
   if (gameObject.name == "Sphere 1(Clone)" && isClicked )
   {
       GUI.Label(new Rect(xpos,260,400,100), "B");
   }
}
```

you can try this one.. all the best..